# Set a cookie and redirect after nginx basic auth succeeds

Tags: nginx

How do I set a cookie and redirect right after an NGINX auth_basic succeeds on the same server?

It seems that some combination `satisfy`, `auth_basic`, or `auth_request` is needed for this, but the documentation only covers the case where authentication is outsourced to some external server.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there should be a better way, but you can trick `try_files` into doing this for you if you use an internal location.

```
location /cookie-drop {
  auth_basic "Please authenticate";
  auth_basic_user_file /your/htpasswd/file;
  # Using null as a hardcoded nonexistent file
  try_files null @cookie-drop;
}

location @cookie-drop {
  internal;
  add_header Set-Cookie "token=foo;Domain=example.com;Path=/";
  return 302 https://$host/
}
```

If you put the `return 302` inside the `/cookie-drop` location, it will ignore the `auth_basic` setting. The `try_files` setting is the only thing I could find to redirect to an internal location like this. Maybe there's a better way though.